# Json structure in mariadb and java structure

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I use spring boot with spring data jpa and mariadb 10.7

I have a class with a lot of relation.

public class Testament {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="testament_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="testament_id_seq",sequenceName="testament_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    TestamentInfo testamentInfo;
    
}

public class TestamentInfo{

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="testament", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    TestamentOwner owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testament",  orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Donation> donations;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testament",  orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Person> executors;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testament",  orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Person> alternativeExecutor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testament",  orphanRemoval = true)
    List<RestHeritage> restHeritages;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testament",  orphanRemoval = true)
    List<String> otherDisposition;

    LocalDate signedDate;
    String signedCity;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDate createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    LocalDate updatedAt;
}
```

This class is used to generated a pdf document.

A lot of query is done on the db.

I would like to have TestamentInfo like a json column in db.

Comment: How do you want to handle the referential integrity between TestamentInfo and its many OneToMany relations to Person, Donation and RestHeritage? Store their data in the same clob/JSON column too? Just write a converter for TestamentInfo to/from JSON and mark property with the Column and Convert annotations. PS you cannot have a OneToMany mapping on List<String> type (otherDisposition) - it can only belong on entities, and String cannot have a testament property within it for the back pointer.

Comment: I think TestamentInfo should be a json column and i could remove all anotation (one to many)

Comment: That doesn't explain how you want to treat the Person, RestHeritage and Donation instances it references. Are they stored in tables, or are you going to serialize that data into JSON too? Chances are good that it is building up these object instance references that are the problem you have with performance. You can serialize it all into one clob/JSON column (plenty of examples with a converter) or optimize how you are fetching this data when you need it. Or both.

Comment: would like to serialize into json too